# soql relation on lookup

Tags: soql

I have 2 objects from custom2 has a lookup relation to custom1 through field__c Now I have to delete some of the records of custom2 based on  custom field on custom1 object when it is false.

How to get all the records and delete from custom2 based on this field filter on custom1?

Comment: You are going to need to write an `Apex Trigger` for this functionality. You should start working on it and come back with more specific questions as they arise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field you are using to filter is a boolean field.

```
List<Custom2__c> delList = [select id from Custom2__c WHERE field__r.filterFiled__c = false];
Delete delList;
```

Comment: No exception handling?

Comment: Thanks Adrian. @Harish - you need to put delete or any other DML statement in a try catch statement, so that you can catch exception and handle accordingly.